# depending on input of user and the name, i want to print different things

Tags: c, char

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main ()
{    
    char strg1 [10] = "john" ;
    char strg2 [10] = "mike" ;
    printf("Enter the name:");
    
    scanf(" %s%s", strg1, strg2 );

    if (strg1 < strg2);
    {
       printf("First condition");
    }

    if (strg 1 > strg2 );
    {
       printf("Second condition");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Im not sure how to write if one of the keywords like mike or john are written by the user, which "condition" to print.

Comment: @kabanus I fail to see any way you might have read the question and thought your comment to be helpful. You will have to elaborate.

Comment: Jonathan. Do you want to cover the situation whe the user inputs only one word, instead of two? Or what condition to you try to implement? Equality (e.g. "John John")? Length (e.g. "a abc")? Alphabetical sorting (e.g. "abc abd")? You will have to explain a lot more. Please provide sample inputs and corresponding desired output.

Comment: @Jonathan Granado I already make a solution! You cant compare strings like that on C, you can check it below, and you have a little errors on your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need have an array to get what user introduces, you cant equalize your array with mike or john already defined to get the other string! So you have 2 aways of do that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char strg1 [10] = "mike";
    char strg2 [10] = "john";
    char input [10];
    printf("Enter the name: ");

    scanf(" %s", input);

    if (strcmp(strg1, input) == 0)
    {
       printf("%s", strg1);
    }

    if (strcmp(strg2, input) == 0)
    {
       printf("%s", strg2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

or another way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char strg1 [10];

    printf("Enter the name: ");

    scanf(" %s", strg1);

    if (strcmp(strg1, "john") == 0)
    {
       printf("%s", strg1);
    }

    if (strcmp(strg1, "mike") == 0)
    {
       printf("%s", strg1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I knew I was doing something wrong with equalizing the array thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing memory address values, but you want to compare the data, which are located at the specific locations. As mentioned, if the length of the strings are relevant 'strlen', for the content 'strncmp'.